# How to get single record in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I've a table, how to get single record on same value in multiple rows.
Eg:-

```
Dbname size devicepath
Db1.   100. Emc#123
Db1.   100. Emc#123av_2
Db2.   150. Emc#145av
Db2.   150. Emc#145av_4
```

Desire out put table

```
Dbname size devicepath
Db1.   100. Emc#123av
Db2.   150. Emc#145av
```

Comment: Why `Emc#123av` and not `Emc#123av_2` in your output? Same question for `Emc#145av` instead of `Emc#145av_4`. Are all `devicepaths` formatted the same way, with a trailing underscore and **single digit** number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much information about how to pick a record instead of other one. For example , for `Db1` , why the value is not `Emc#123` and why the value  `Emc#123av` (which is not present in the data set) .
Also , `_2` it's always removed ?

With this few info, you can use `MAX`

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Dbname] varchar(4), [size] int, [devicepath] varchar(11))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Dbname], [size], [devicepath])
VALUES
    ('Db1.', 100., 'Emc#123'),
    ('Db1.', 100., 'Emc#123av_2'),
    ('Db2.', 150., 'Emc#145av'),
    ('Db2.', 150., 'Emc#145av_4');
```

Appling `MAX`,

```
SELECT 
    DbName,Size,
    MAX(DevicePath) as DevicePath
FROM Table1
GROUP BY
    DbName,Size
```

The output:

| DbName | Size | DevicePath |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Db1. | 100 | Emc#123av_2 |
| Db2. | 150 | Emc#145av_4 |

And for removing the `_2`, use

```
  SUBSTRING(DevicePath,
              1,
              ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_',DevicePath),0)-1,
                    LEN(DevicePath)
                    )
           )as DevicePath
```

The final query :

```
SELECT
  DbName,Size,
  SUBSTRING(DevicePath,
              1,
              ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_',DevicePath),0)-1,
                    LEN(DevicePath)
                    )
           )as DevicePath
FROM
  (  
    SELECT 
        DbName,Size,
        MAX(DevicePath) as DevicePath
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY
        DbName,Size
  )as src
```

| DbName | Size | DevicePath |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Db1. | 100 | Emc#123av |
| Db2. | 150 | Emc#145av |

test [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BUD1dEn-)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Dbname] varchar(4), [size] int, [devicepath] varchar(11))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Dbname], [size], [devicepath])
VALUES
    ('Db1.', 100, 'Emc#123'),
    ('Db1.', 100, 'Emc#123av_2'),
    ('Db2.', 150, 'Emc#145av'),
    ('Db2.', 150, 'Emc#145av_4'),
    ('Db1.', 100, 'Emc#156av'),
    ('Db1.', 100, 'Emc#156av_1')
;
```

your query :

```
;with cteSource AS
(SELECT 
  DbName,Size,DevicePath,
  SUBSTRING(DevicePath,
              1,
              ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('av',DevicePath),0)-1,
                    LEN(DevicePath)
                    )
           )as DevicePath_New
FROM Table1
)
SELECT  DbName,Size,DevicePath
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT DbName,Size,DevicePath, 
         ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY DevicePath_New 
         ORDER BY DevicePath ASC) as rn  
     FROM cteSource as s
  )as s
WHERE s.rn = 1
```

This output:

```
DbName  Size    DevicePath
Db1.    100     Emc#123
Db2.    150     Emc#145av
Db1.    100     Emc#156av
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/P1c17Cyx

Answer (score 0):

As stated, it is difficult to guess why the desired result should be the way you describe. My guess is that you want to exclude rows where there is another rows devicepath that is a substring of the current rows devicepath.

```
select * from table1 t1
where not exists (
  select 1 from table1 t2 
  where t1.devicepath like t2.devicepath + '%'
    and t2.devicepath <> t1.devicepath
)
```

Extended [VD Max](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/223385/vd-max) [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1o2SewNY)